# Taking javascript input

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am developing a CLI using Enquirer. I want user of the CLI to write javascript on a json.

So, i want something like this :

```
Create a Rule on the the data 

const model = {
      reviews: {
        '5': [
          {
            customerId: 'A2OKPZ5S9F78PD',
            rating: '5',
            asin: 'asin2',
            reviewStatus: 'APPROVED',
            reviewId: 'R379DKACZQRXME',
          },
        ],
        '4': [
          {
            customerId: 'A2OKPZ5S9F78PD',
            rating: '4',
            asin: 'asin2',
            reviewStatus: 'APPROVED',
            reviewId: 'R379DKACZQRXME',
          },
        ],
      },
      entityType: 'LIVE_EVENT',
      entityId: 'event2',
    };
```

Then user writes the rule.

```
Object.values(model.reviews).forEach(reviews =>
      (reviews as any).forEach(review => {
        if (parseInt(review.rating) < 3 && attributes.reviewId.Value.includes(review.reviewId)) {
          output.push({
            exceptionName: `Customer ${review.customerId} left a review ${review.reviewId} with rating ${review.rating}`,
          });
        }
      })
    );
```

While writing this rule, Since it is on the above json model, I want to provide autocomplete options on javascript and validate if it is correct javascript.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it sounds like you want to take the `model` object and write it to a JSON file.

If this is your goal, simply do the following:

```
import { writeFileSync } from "fs";

// Define the model
const model: any = { foo: bar };

// Transform the model object to JSON
const modelJSON: string = JSON.stringify(model, null, 4); // Indents the JSON 4-spaces

// Write the modelJSON to `model.json`
writeFileSync("./model.json", modelJSON);
```

The above is TypeScript, but the standard JavaScript version is basically the same. Make sure you add `@types/node` to your `package.json` file if you're using TypeScript - hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am looking for user to write a rule in javascript given this model input.

Comment: Perhaps then it would be best for the user to simply to write a `config.js` file where the rules can be defined, and your Enquirer CLI can attempt to read in that file using standard `require` syntax - just do `path.resolve(process.cwd, "config.js")` to get the path

Comment: I want to validate syntax. User can write incorrect syntax.